# Cadastrar usuários autenticados com o Facebook no Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Boa noite! Pessoal, estou usando login com Facebook no meu app e gostaria de cadastrar as informações do usuário no realtime database ou firestore, como o nome e email por exemplo, eu já recuperei as informações do usuário logado, já fiz a autenticação, mas não sei como salvar esses dados, consigo salvar tranquilamente quando uso o método de email e senha, mas com o facebook o método de login é diferente. Qual a melhor forma de eu salvar esses dados ?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void firebaseAutenticacaoFacebook(AccessToken accessToken) {

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential( credential )
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        
                        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                        
                        usuario.setEmail( user.getEmail() );
                        usuario.setNome ( user.getDisplayName());
                        usuario.setFoto ( user.getPhotoUrl().toString());


                        MainScreen();

                    } else {

                        String excecao = "";

                        try
                        {
                            throw task.getException();

                        }catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e)
                        {
                            excecao = "Este email ja foi cadastrado!";

                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            excecao = "Erro ao logar usuário!" + e.getMessage();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), excecao , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}

 public void MainScreen(){

    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conforme a documentação em [Ler e gravar dados no android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br#java)

Tenha a instância:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

a classe User

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

e a função que irá salvar no firebase:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

pela amostra do seu código, pode-se fazer:

```
//...
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

writeNewUser(user.getUid(), user.getDisplayName(), user.getEmail());
//...
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, única curiosidade é que esse processo da credencial sempre vai ser chamada ao fazer uma solicitação de login com o Facebook, se eu vier salvar por exemplo a idade do usuário junto ao nome e Email já salvo e em seguida logar novamente com a mesma conta, essa função para salvar no Firebase é chamada novamente e irá sobrescrever o usuário atual, ou seja, qualquer alteração futura dentro de um usuário vai ser perdida caso o usuário realize o login novamente, deixando apenas as informações iniciais, Nome e Email.